# Architectural / Construction Term "On Center" in Spanish

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, construcción-y-obra

I'm looking to properly translate an architectural text and I want to make sure I use accurate expressions, specifically for Latin America.

When, for example, talking about screw placement, the spacing is mentioned as:

> Minimum 24"oc

Or:

> 24"o.c.

I realize it could simply be translated as *24" en el centro* or *24" sobre centro* but I'd like some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like there's no abbreviation for "OC" but it is known as "Separacion de centro a centro" (separation from center to center)

another way of how it is called "centros" like

> *las vigas se colocan en los centros de 16 pulgadas*
>
> > the beams are placed in the 16'(inches) centers

Example :

> Si el uso de cerchas pre-construidos de techo o la construcción de vigas más tradicionales, vigas del techo se colocan normalmente 24 pulgadas de distancia. El otro espacio más comúnmente encontrado es centros de 16 pulgadas. A veces, los constructores deciden utilizar una distancia entre estos dos puntos. Por lo general, esto significaría que las vigas se colocan en los centros de 19,2 pulgadas. También existen otras excepciones cuando los constructores están creando diseños especializados que no estén incluidos en las especificaciones de construcción estándar, o cuando hacer adaptaciones al final de un edificio cuando la distancia total de la cubierta no puede ser dividido en espaciado idéntico entre cada conjunto de viguetas.

source: 
https://www.digfineart.com/2Lw4dj0b5/